# Jetpack Compose: `derivedStateOf` that depends on a composable function parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So, here is an interesting situation I am in:

`ComposableA` (CA) calls `ComposableB` (CB) with a parameter `email`. In `ComposableB`, I want to have an `emailError` `state` that depends on `email`. Everytime the `email` changes (or some other event like FocusChange), I want to recompute the `emailError` state and force a recomposition of the `Composable`.

In `CB`, If I use `derivedStateOf` or `mutableStateOf` without remember, I get a linter error like this:

[image]

I can suppress that by adding `@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")` annotation but that doesn't force the state to be recomputed even when the focus or email changes. If I just use a variable, the compose engine wouldn't know that the composable UI depends on that value and would not recompose it even if there is a change in value.

Here is the code:

`ComposableB`

```
fun CB(
  emailValue: TextFieldValue = TextFieldValue("", TextRange.Zero),
  onEmailChanged: (emailValue: TextFieldValue) -> Unit = {},
  focusedTextField: FeatTextField = FeatTextField.Email,
  onFocusedTextField: (textField: FeatTextField) -> Unit = {}
) {
  // Error is derived from emailAddress
  val emailError by derivedStateOf {
    Timber.tag("StateTest").i("EmailValue: ${emailValue.text}")
    focusedTextField != SignInTextField.Email && !Validator.validateEmail(emailValue.text)
  }

  ... Rest of the code that renders the composable using focusedTextField, email and emailError values
```

`ComposableA`

```
.... Maintains the state and calls CB

fun CA(
  emailValue = emailValue,
  onEmailChanged = { vm.newUiState(copy(emailValue = it)) },
  focusedTextField = focusedTextField,
  onFocusedTextField = { focusedTextField = it }
)
```

I can make error as one of the parameters and hoist the state in `CA` but I am trying to avoid that because I want to keep CB as independent as possible.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Thank you!

1. I have tried several options: using `mutableStateOf`, `derivedStateOf` and `rememberUpdateState`.
2. I am expecting a directional help. Suggestions around which is the right Class/Function to use

Comment: why not just use `remember { derivedStateOf { ... } }`?

Comment: that wouldn’t work because the state wouldn’t be recomputed on recompositions

Comment: You can pass parameters to `remember` to fix that. Unless you want to recompute on *every* recomposition, in which case just don't use a `State` object at all.

Comment: if you don't use `State` object, the `Composable` which uses that state won't be recomposed if the value changes.

Comment: This topic is is covered in detail in this medium post: https://stefma.medium.com/jetpack-compose-remember-mutablestateof-derivedstateof-and-remembersaveable-explained-270dbaa61b8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you shouldn't be using `derivedStateOf` and probably don't even need `remember`.

`derivedStateOf` should only be used if the expression reads mutable state values. If no mutable state values are read, then the `derivedStateOf` is providing no value and is overhead you don't need. Also, `derivedStateOf` is only really useful if the value produced will change less frequently than the data it reads.

If the parameter values are not changing frequently then the normal skipping of a composable function might be all you need here. `CB` will only execute when one of its parameters change (assuming they are all stable).

If, however, one of the parameters is changing a lot and is not part of the expensive calculation, consider using `remember` for the expensive calculation. Be sure to pass in the values that are changing as parameters to `remember` so Compose knows when to re-evaluate the remembered expression. For example,

```
val emailError by remember(emailValue.text, focusedTextField) {
    Timber.tag("StateTest").i("EmailValue: ${emailValue.text}")
    focusedTextField != SignInTextField.Email && !Validator.validateEmail(emailValue.text)
  }
```

However, as noted above, since these two parameter are the only ones likely to be changing, the skipping Compose is already doing might be enough.

The article https://stefma.medium.com/jetpack-compose-remember-mutablestateof-derivedstateof-and-remembersaveable-explained-270dbaa61b8 goes into this in more detail.